# Scrollview is not visible

Tags: android, scrollview

Below is given a code block which repeat five time  on my layout

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_clock_homescreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" android:layout_height="70dp">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_sound_selected"
                android:visibility="visible" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/airpurifier_cat" android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"></ImageView>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_sound_selected"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button android:background="@drawable/soundselect"
                        android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF" android:text="Select Sound" android:id="@+id/button_soundselect1"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@drawable/ipod_play"
                        android:id="@+id/button_player1_play" android:layout_height="30dp"></Button>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/pitch_balance"
                        android:id="@+id/imagebutton_home_player1_setting">
                    </ImageButton>
                    <SeekBar android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/volumebutton"
                        android:id="@+id/seekbar_player1" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"></SeekBar>

                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_home_mediaplayer1_setting"
                android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="40dp">
                <Button android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ipod_pause" android:id="@+id/button_player1_setting_playpause"></Button>
                <Button android:layout_width="50dp" android:background="@drawable/ipod_fforward"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button_player1_setting_forward"></Button>
                <Button android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:background="@drawable/ipod_bback"
                    android:id="@+id/button_player1_setting_reverse"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"></Button>
                <Button android:background="@drawable/ipod_loop_off"
                    android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button_player1_setting_loopplay"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

i have applied scrollview on this block in this way, i enclosed  these five repeated blocks in a linear layout and put inside a scroll view  with width & height:fill_parent.

This is the resultant code

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="620px" android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="true" android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- PLAYER ONE START -->
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_clock_homescreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/rel1"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp" android:layout_height="70dp">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_sound_selected"
                android:visibility="visible" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/airpurifier_cat" android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"></ImageView>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image_sound_selected"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <Button android:background="@drawable/soundselect"
                        android:layout_width="180dp" android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:textColor="#FFF" android:text="Select Sound" android:id="@+id/button_soundselect1"></Button>
                    <Button android:layout_width="40dp" android:background="@drawable/ipod_play"
                        android:id="@+id/button_player1_play" android:layout_height="30dp"></Button>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/pitch_balance"
                        android:id="@+id/imagebutton_home_player1_setting">
                    </ImageButton>
                    <SeekBar android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/volumebutton"
                        android:id="@+id/seekbar_player1" android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="140dp"></SeekBar>

                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout_home_mediaplayer1_setting"
                android:visibility="invisible" android:layout_height="40dp">
                <Button android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ipod_pause" android:id="@+id/button_player1_setting_playpause"></Button>
                <Button android:layout_width="50dp" android:background="@drawable/ipod_fforward"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button_player1_setting_forward"></Button>
                <Button android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:background="@drawable/ipod_bback"
                    android:id="@+id/button_player1_setting_reverse"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"></Button>
                <Button android:background="@drawable/ipod_loop_off"
                    android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/button_player1_setting_loopplay"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

i am confused what is problem and scrollview is not visible...

Comment: height is 620px here, but i tried with fill_parent also.. it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this tag to your ScrollView

```xml
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```